# How to add/push deep level hierarchical data in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following is the VueJs data object.

```
menu: {
    title_en: '',
    title_ar: '',
    price: '',
    preferences: 
    [
        {
            title_en: '',
            title_ar: '',
            items: [
                {
                    title_en: '',
                    title_ar: '',
                    price: '',
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I can easily add data at the first level, as below.

```
this.menu.preferences.push({
    title_en: '',
    title_ar: '',
    items: [
        {
            title_en: '',
            title_ar: '',
            price: '',
        }
    ] 
});
```

But this time, how can we add/push data to second or third level, when needed. Tried below but failed.

```
this.menu.preferences.items.push({
    title_en: '',
    title_ar: '',
    price: '',
});
```

Comment: `this.menu.preferences[0].items.push(/*...*/)`

Comment: this.menu.preferences is an array and not an object
we need to access the items key in the object at index 0
so we'll access it this was `this.menu.preferences[0]`
to access the key `items`
`this.menu.preferences[0].items` which is an array, so now we need to push to it
`this.menu.preferences[0].items.push(enter your object here)`